# Looking for timeline of a twitter user using twitter4j 3.03

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to retrieve the timeline of a twitter user using twitter4j. I was able to do this using version 2.6 but now I upgraded to 3.03 and started getting authenticaton error from twitter.

> 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth)
>   were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer
>   key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
>   message - Could not authenticate you code - 32

This is how I retrieve a twitter object

```
TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(
                                                new ConfigurationBuilder().setDebugEnabled(true).
                                                setOAuthConsumerKey(oAuthConsumerKey).
                                                setOAuthConsumerSecret(oAuthConsumerSecret).
                                                setJSONStoreEnabled(true).
                                                build());
twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret));
```

When I retrieve a twitter object like this and try to get a different user than the authenticated user I got an authentication error. Here is the code for retrieving the user:

```
user = twitter.showUser(userName);
```

Before the upgrade I was able to retrieve any user who has a public profile, but now I can't retrieve any user other than the authenticated user itself. Am I doing smtg wrong here, Do I need to get permission from the user to lookup for his timeline, which I don't believe because when I use oauth tool of twitter I am able to retrieve the user without getting any permission from the user.

I am using twitter4j version 3.03.

Comment: Apparently old api was accepting userNames starting with "@" whereas the new version just throws this strange error. After removing the "@" from the searched user name everything worked without any problem.

Comment: Kindly post it as an answer so that it can be helpful to others

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, cheers

Comment: That's nice.cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently old api was accepting userNames starting with "@" whereas the new version just throws this strange error. After removing the "@" from the searched user name everything worked without any problem.